# Different TTF files for different font in android

Tags: android, fonts, textview, truetype, android-assets

I want to use different font styles. I'am using the following code for different font style. How can i get other styles? Can i have some other styles in same ttf file? Where do i get ttf files of different fonts?

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf"); 
txt.setText("This is sample text with Chantelli Antiqua font style.");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for only styles with the same font you can add style to your Typeface like this,

```
txt.setTypeface(font,Style.BOLD);
txt.setTypeface(font,Style.ITALIC); 
txt.setTypeface(font,Style.BOLD_ITALIC);
```

Comment: How do i get ttf files of the other font types like Arial, Calibri, TimesNewRoman etc..??

Comment: I doubt that you have to download the required ttf files and no other way to achieve different styles else.

Comment: Thanks Selva. From here i got different ttf files. http://www.webpagepublicity.com/free-fonts.html

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, there is no restriction on how many different fonts you can use in your app. Without getting into the merits of the above statement of course.

I think when you say other styles from TTF files, you mean the bold, italic, normal, medium, etc, styles of a font. The answer is: not from the same TTF file. If you open your *Fonts* folder in *Windows* for example, and then open a specific font, you will see multiple files specific to each *style*. You will need to copy all the files that you need in your app and paste them in your apps "**assets/fonts**" folder.

Second, if you are looking for fonts installed on your computer, you will find them in your *c:\Windows\Fonts* folder. If you are looking for more fonts to choose from, you will find a lot on these sites:

http://www.google.com/webfonts

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/