# Change TextView Font?

Tags: android

How can I change font type in Android TextView?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome!"
    android:textSize="20sp"  />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`android:typeface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atypeface) attribute. For example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome!"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="20sp"  />
```

The XML attribute only allows the values `normal`, `sans`, `serif`, and `monospace`. If you want to use a different `Typeface` (perhaps a custom one that you ship with your app), you will have to do it in code by calling [`setTypeface()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29) for the view after the TextView is loaded.

Comment: Now what are some of the different type faces?

Comment: @apw2012 - You can usually only depend on a single set of type faces being present in the system--the ones accessed through the allowed XML values. It used to be "Droid Sans", "Droid Sans Mono" and "Droid Serif". As of Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0), it's the "Roboto" family (described [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html)). For anything else, you'll need to ship it with your app and load it using one of the `TypeFace.createFrom...` methods (such as @Siddharth describes).

Answer (score 6):

To add to *Ted Hopp's* answer, if you are looking at a custom font for your `TextView`, in your `Activity` from where you reference the `TextView`, use this code example:

```
Typeface blockFonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"ROBOTO-MEDIUM_0.TTF");
TextView txtSampleTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
txtSampleTxt.setTypeface(blockFonts);
```

Although, before you can use this, you will need to copy the font/s of your choice in the `assets` folder.

You can also look at one of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10680119/450534) on SO which has a couple of websites you can use to download fonts. They are:

http://www.google.com/webfonts

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

Comment: To clarify, you only need to create a `fonts` sub-folder if you want to use a path that starts with `"fonts/"` as the asset name as you are doing. Fonts can also be loaded from the root assets folder.

Comment: Typeface 
  blockFonts = 
  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Lobster.TTF"); 
  TextView txtSampleTxt = (TextView) 
  findViewById(R.id.welcome); 
  txtSampleTxt.setTypeface(blockFonts);

Comment: Okay so the thing is crashing when it opens. I put the code provided and changed it to the needed font under the oncreate/setlayout in the java

Comment: @apw2012: I will typically drop the font in the folder, then click on it, press F2 for the rename dialog, select the entire font name with the extension and then paste it in my java code. Please look at my edit after being corrected by _Ted_

Comment: I'm on android, not a computer. I've been trying to use AIDE.

Comment: @apw2012: Ohhh..... well, then just make sure you type it out to the T. Including the case in the extension too.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically set the desire  font by placing your font file (example.tff) style in 
Assets/fonts and then give your own string into fontpath variable

```
    String fontPath="fonts/Unkempt-Regular.ttf";
    TextView aboutus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.aboutus);
    Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
    aboutus.setTypeface(type);
```