# How to create countdown timer with animation on the View

Tags: android, countdowntimer

How can create a `View` like this

[image]

In the quiz game, each level, this `View` will countdown the time, the faster the answer is chosen, the higher score will be. So, the first thing is how to get the time on this `View`.

Comment: should be easy enough. Find or design the alarm clock as a png and create an image view as its source to display it. Create a Text view for the seconds  and get a nice font for it.  - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ -- You put the textview inside something like a frame layout so you can position it in the center of the alarm clock, and use a countdown timer to change the textviews text, seconds  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android  - how to change a textviews font using Typeface  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553727/change-textview-font

Comment: I got it, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a layout for your alarm drawable, including an ImageView and a TextView that overlays on it.

**Initialize your objects before onCreate():**

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
TextView tvTime;
```

**Then create a method and add this to it, or add it to onCreate():**

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        tvTime.setText(String.valueOf((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        endGame(); //End the game or do whatever you want.
    }
}.start();
```

where 60000 is the total countdown time in milliseconds and 1000 is the time interval for onTick in milliseconds.