# Is it possible to customize the BottomNavBar without Icons, Change the text and Changing the selected tab background

Tags: android, customization, bottomnavigationview

[BottomBarNavigationBar template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw7cW.jpg)

BottomBarNavigationBar

Note : It should follow google material design guidelines also.

Comment: The [material design guidelines for bottom navigation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html) are quite specific on the requirement for icons, text style, and the highlight behavior.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Please click on Image link for the Info .

Comment: That is not a material design bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Thank you @ianhanniballake ok may be I Need to customize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Removing Bottom Navigation Bar is not possible in non-rooted android device. But you can set buttons to just above the Bottom navigation Bar,it would work fine and look nice.
2. For changing text style you can go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553727/change-textview-font). It would clear your doubt.
3. Changing the selected tab is definitely possible. For this go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640563/how-do-i-change-a-tab-background-color-when-using-tablayout)

And finally I am sorry that I am giving just link here, as all the questions you asked are already available on SO.

So please, next time when you ask any question, then do a detail research about it then post that here.

Comment: If we use Buttons instead of google's BottomNavigationBar we miss the auto hiding feature.  For more info "https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html"  @Swr7der

Comment: Thanks but the link is broken.
Thanks for the info sir @Srikanth

Comment: The autohide feature does not seem to work anymore with the recent update. Any ideas?